# How can I update nested List in Map that's all inserted to a List? Eg. List<Map<String, dynamic>>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update or add to the end of the Lists that are in a Map and all inserted into a List that contains those maps. The List name is 'classes', what I have tried doing was using dot notation, so classes.index.example, but that doesn't work. Why...let's say I have two indexes in the list, If I go ahead and update index 0, the 'questions' and 'answers' will get inserted into that correct index, But for some reason, it will delete index 1 and any other that was created. It's as if It's overwriting all the data, but I don't understand why, I am not using 'setData()' Also, if I leave 'title' out, that too will get deleted??

```
 Future updattingUserData(int index, List<dynamic> question, List<dynamic> answer, String title) async {
    return await _collref.document(uid).updateData({
      "classes.$index.questions":  FieldValue.arrayUnion(question),
      "classes.$index.answers":  FieldValue.arrayUnion(answer),
      //"classes.$index.title": title
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have the capability of changing an array element knowing only its index within an array field.  What you will have to do is read the document, modify the classes array in memory, then update the entire classes array field back to the document.

Comment: So like a transaction? Do you have any method suggestions or docs to read that will help?

Comment: You can use a transaction if you want, but that's not required.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I finally got it!